# Изучение .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, .net, silverlight

Занялся изучением .net технологий. начал с C#, базовые знания приобрел. Теперь стал вопрос, что изучать дальше?
Wpf, silverlight или asp.net? В какой последовательности вообще лучше всего изучать технологии и на чем делать акцент? Интересует как веб разработка, так и разработка десктоп приложений. Но в то же время, не хочу далеко уходить от возможности перейти на разработку мобильных приложений ) Помоги, обьясните

Comment: Спасибо за советы, теперь по порядку
ganouver, совершенно согласен, обучение на реальных примерах намного лучше, но где брать эти примеры (задачи) которые могут использоваться в жизни?
BlackOverlord, читал я про них, но акцент сделать на какой то одно не могу, на данный момент охватить хочу все, но не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: Да для начала - я знаю кучу народу которые сами себе делали маленькие напоминалки. Напишите себе сайт. Или поступите так, как советует wind. а насчет "на данный момент охватить хочу все, но не знаю с чего начать" - напомню Козьму Пруткова [http://bibliotekar.ru/encSlov/13/185.htm]

Comment: Про "охватить все" - это я образно ) Просто на данный момент интересует и сильверлайт (как возможность писать под мобильные платформы), так и wpf/winforms для десктопных. Совет winda хороший, но я не знаю, на чем учиться. По книгам далеко не уйдешь, нужна практика. А где брать эти задания, вот вопрос...регистрироваться на фриланс сайтах думаю толку не будет, т.к. опыта нет...

Comment: **Идти работать. Любое направление по C#.**

Answer (score 10):

Не изучайте впустую, все равно не угадаете. Ищите реальную задачу, желательно интересную вам лично. А уже потом рассматривайте все технологии с точки зрения пригодности для этой задачи. И - вперед и с песней. На практике все усваивается гораздо быстрее и надежнее.
Вдумайтесь в разницу между фразами:

1. **Я прочитал книгу про WPF и написал 2 (5, 10) упражнений**
2. **Я написал работающую программу на WPF и пользуюсь ею**

В каком случае ваша личная мотивация будет выше?

Answer (score 2):

Хм... Ну я бы на твоем месте прочитал о каждой из технологий, на той же википедии и сделал бы вывод для себя, что мне больше нужно, на основе описаных вами желаний сложно дать ответ, но я бы выбрал **Wpf**, т.к. его графическая подсистема входит в состав **.NET**, проще говоря, если изучил **.NET**, то **Wpf** будет куда легче для понимания.

Answer (score 2):

Найдите сперва контору, в которую бы вы хотели попасть и ознакомьтесь с их требования - вот вам и список того, что учить далее. Если же вы прирожденный фрилансер, то я бы на вашем месте ориентировался опять же на рынок. Учить сильвер только потому, что он используется в разных местах сомнительное и дорогое удовольствие - найдете ли вы себе работу или заказ на нем? Если уверены, что да - учите, если нет, то...

Answer (score 1):

Раз вас все сразу интересует, то Silverlight - самая везде-применимая. И на Windows Phone на ней делают все приложения (те, к-ые не игры); и в веб-разработке его можно применить; и, с небольшими танцами с бубнами (танцевать вам, не пользователю, так что это не страшно), даже на десктоп можно разрабатывать.